# keras fit_generator doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, keras, yield-keyword

I am currently trying to get the fit_generator to work with my generator but this somehow does not work that well..

Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras import metrics
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation, Lambda, Reshape,Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv1D,Conv2D,MaxPooling2D, MaxPooling1D, Reshape
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras import backend as K
from keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau
from keras.callbacks import CSVLogger
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras.models import load_model



def generator(batch_size):

    global train_input
    train_input = np.random.randint(5,size=(5000,33,45,8,3))
    global train_output
    train_output = np.random.randint(5,size=(5000,15))
    global train_input_concat
    train_input_concat = np.empty((0,33,45,8,3))

    while True:
        for input in train_input:
            input = np.expand_dims(input,axis=0)
            train_input_concat = np.append(train_input_concat,input,axis=0)
            print train_input_concat.shape
            print input.shape
            raw_input("something")
            if (batch_size) == train_input_concat.shape[0]:
                output_train_set = train_output[:batch_size,:]
                train_output = np.delete(train_output,np.s_[:batch_size],axis=0)
                train_output_set = np_utils.to_categorical(output_train_set,145)
                train_input_set = train_input_concat
                del train_input_concat
                train_input_concat = np.empty((0,33,45,8,3))
                print train_input_set.shape
                print train_output_set.shape
                print train_output.shape
                raw_input("Something yield")
                yield train_input_set,train_output_set

def model3():
    stride = 2
    dim = 40
    total_frames_with_deltas = 45
    total_frames = 15
    window_height = 8
    splits = ((40-8)+1)/1

    kernel_number = 150#int(math.ceil(splits))
    list_of_input = [Input(shape = (total_frames_with_deltas,window_height,3)) for i in range(splits)]
    list_of_conv_output = []
    list_of_max_out = []
    for i in range(splits):
        list_of_conv_output.append(Conv2D(filters = kernel_number , kernel_size = (15,6))(list_of_input[i]))
        list_of_max_out.append((MaxPooling2D(pool_size=((2,2)))(list_of_conv_output[i])))

    merge = keras.layers.concatenate(list_of_max_out)
    print merge.shape
    reshape = Reshape((total_frames,-1))(merge)

    dense1 = Dense(units = 1000, activation = 'relu',    name = "dense_1")(reshape)
    dense2 = Dense(units = 1000, activation = 'relu',    name = "dense_2")(dense1)
    dense3 = Dense(units = 145 , activation = 'softmax', name = "dense_3")(dense2)
    #dense4 = Dense(units = 1, activation = 'linear', name = "dense_4")(dense3)


    model = Model(inputs = list_of_input , outputs = dense3)
    model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="SGD" , metrics = [metrics.categorical_accuracy])

    reduce_lr=ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.1, patience=3, verbose=1, mode='auto', epsilon=0.001, cooldown=0)
    stop  = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0, patience=5, verbose=1, mode='auto')

    print model.summary()

    raw_input("okay?")
    hist_current = model.fit_generator(generator(1),
                        steps_per_epoch=1,
                        epochs = 10,
                        verbose = 2,
                        validation_data = None)
model3()
```

Is this generator made correctly?..

because i am getting error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_generator.py", line 90, in <module>
    model3()
  File "test_generator.py", line 89, in model3
    validation_data = None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 87, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1876, in fit_generator
    class_weight=class_weight)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1614, in train_on_batch
    check_batch_axis=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1295, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='model input')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 100, in _standardize_input_data
    'Found: array with shape ' + str(data.shape))
ValueError: The model expects 33 input arrays, but only received one array. Found: array with shape (1, 33, 45, 8, 3)
```

Which I don't understand because it gets one same with 33 inputs? so why cant it  read it?

**edit:**

Here with  list:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras import metrics
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation, Lambda, Reshape,Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv1D,Conv2D,MaxPooling2D, MaxPooling1D, Reshape
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras import backend as K
from keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau
from keras.callbacks import CSVLogger
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras.models import load_model



def generator(batch_size):

    global train_input
    train_input = np.random.randint(5,size=(5000,33,45,8,3))
    global train_output
    train_output = np.random.randint(5,size=(5000,15))
    global train_input_concat
    train_input_concat = np.empty((0,33,45,8,3))

    while True:
        for input in train_input:
            input = np.expand_dims(input,axis=0)
            train_input_concat = np.append(train_input_concat,input,axis=0)
            print train_input_concat.shape
            print input.shape
            raw_input("something")
            if (batch_size) == train_input_concat.shape[0]:
                output_train_set = train_output[:batch_size,:]
                train_output = np.delete(train_output,np.s_[:batch_size],axis=0)
                train_output_set = np_utils.to_categorical(output_train_set,145)
                train_input_set = train_input_concat
                del train_input_concat
                train_input_concat = np.empty((0,33,45,8,3))
                print train_input_set.shape
                print train_output_set.shape
                print train_output.shape
                input_list = np.split(train_input_set,33,axis=1)
                print len(input_list)
                yield ({'train_input': input_list},{'labels':train_output_set})

def model3():
    stride = 2
    dim = 40
    total_frames_with_deltas = 45
    total_frames = 15
    window_height = 8
    splits = ((40-8)+1)/1

    kernel_number = 150#int(math.ceil(splits))
    list_of_input = [Input(shape = (total_frames_with_deltas,window_height,3)) for i in range(splits)]
    list_of_conv_output = []
    list_of_max_out = []
    for i in range(splits):
        list_of_conv_output.append(Conv2D(filters = kernel_number , kernel_size = (15,6))(list_of_input[i]))
        list_of_max_out.append((MaxPooling2D(pool_size=((2,2)))(list_of_conv_output[i])))

    merge = keras.layers.concatenate(list_of_max_out)
    print merge.shape
    reshape = Reshape((total_frames,-1))(merge)

    dense1 = Dense(units = 1000, activation = 'relu',    name = "dense_1")(reshape)
    dense2 = Dense(units = 1000, activation = 'relu',    name = "dense_2")(dense1)
    dense3 = Dense(units = 145 , activation = 'softmax', name = "dense_3")(dense2)
    #dense4 = Dense(units = 1, activation = 'linear', name = "dense_4")(dense3)


    model = Model(inputs = list_of_input , outputs = dense3)
    model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="SGD" , metrics = [metrics.categorical_accuracy])

    reduce_lr=ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.1, patience=3, verbose=1, mode='auto', epsilon=0.001, cooldown=0)
    stop  = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0, patience=5, verbose=1, mode='auto')

    print model.summary()

    raw_input("okay?")
    hist_current = model.fit_generator(generator(1),
                        steps_per_epoch=1,
                        epochs = 10,
                        verbose = 2,
                        validation_data = None)
model3()
```

which gives me error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_generator.py", line 93, in <module>
    model3()
  File "test_generator.py", line 92, in model3
    validation_data = None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 88, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1868, in fit_generator
    batch_size = list(x.values())[0].shape[0]
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Comment: train_input_set should be a list of 33 numpy arrays containing your inputs of shape (batch_size, total_frames_with_deltas,window_height,3)

Comment: No... the array is (batch_size, 33, total_frames_with__deltas,window_height,3)

Comment: Well... if you don't wanna fix your issue have it your way lol i'm telling you that this is wrong, do what you want with it

Comment: I am not sure i understand.. the shape of the `train_input_set`is as i've specified.  but ok.. I will throw it into a list..

Comment: Your model has several inputs, different inputs should be thrown as a list and each input should be a numpy array :) so try to change your generator, it should work

Comment: So i added it, but for some reason am i getting some error with the list don't have atribute shape.

Comment: Edit your post with the new code, i would like to have a complete insight of whats coming out of the generator

Comment: The new code is added under the edit.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/raw/FHNhvRNj

Comment: won't work. What  you need to yield is a something like this : yield (inputs,outputs). Where inputs is a list : len(inputs) = 33 and inputs[0].shape = (batch_size, 45, 8, 3). I tested your code and it yields inputs as a list, this is correct but inputs[0].shape = (batch_size,1,45,8,3).

Comment: I've fixed it it works :) thanks for the help

Comment: @Fixining_ranges if you found a solution, can you please add it as an answer to this question?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a case of using fit_generator() on a model with multiple inputs which may have different shapes, the following custom generator example for two inputs per sample might be of help:

```
def data_gen(input1_shape, input2_shape, batch_size):
    while True:
        input1_batch = []
        input2_batch = []
        labels_batch = []
        for i in range(batch_size):
            # Assume inp1 and inp2 are two inputs for a sample
            val = np.random.randint(0, 100)
            inp1 = np.full(input1_shape, val)
            inp2 = np.full(input2_shape, val)

            # Get label
            labels_batch.append(np.random.choice([0, 1]))

            # Parallel lists for each input
            input1_batch.append(inp1)
            input2_batch.append(inp2)

        # Yield the accumulated batch
        yield [input1_batch, input2_batch], labels_batch
```